# Problem with requests module when used together with argparse. I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"

Tags: python, request, argparse

---

This module gets the links from web pages using BeautifulSoup.

```py
import requests
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class WebScraper:
    def __init__(self, page_url: str, intended_tag: str):
        self.page_url = page_url
        self.intended_tag = intended_tag

    def get_links(self):
        response = requests.get(self.page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        links = [page_link.get('href') for page_link in soup.find_all(self.intended_tag)]

        return links


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get all the links from the page')
    parser.add_argument('--page-url', '-p', type=str, required=True, help='Enter URL of the page')
    parser.add_argument('--tag', '-t', type=str, required=True, help='Enter the tag to look for')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    scraper = WebScraper(args.page_url, args.tag)
    links_info = scraper.get_links()

    for link in links_info:
        print(link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

When the code is used with argparse(code above). When I try to pass parameters with argparse I'm getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'".

```
import requests
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class WebScraper:
    def __init__(self, page_url: str, intended_tag: str):
        self.page_url = page_url
        self.intended_tag = intended_tag

    def get_links(self):
        response = requests.get(self.page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        links = [page_link.get('href') for page_link in soup.find_all(self.intended_tag)]

        return links

scraper = WebScraper('page_url', 'a')
page_links  = scraper.get_links()

for link in page_links:
   print(links)
```

---

When I'm not using argparse all works fine.

Comment: Right after the `parse_args` line, add a debugging `print(args)`.  Is that what you expect?  Also show the script calling line.